# WPF Closing a Window from the a UserControl MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, datacontext

I currently have a problem with my `Binding` because upon pressing a `Button`, it should close a certain `Window` but it doesn't. This is a more detailed description of the situation:

In my Application, I have the following button:

[image]

Upon pressing it, a new `Window` is launched. It contains a `UserControl` and is used as a `DialogBox` to confirm that the user wants to save all changes. This is the code that launches the `DialogBox (Window)`. Note that the window is passed by reference:

```
private void OpenRegisterDialog(string changes)
    {
        window = new Window
        {
            Title = "Confirmation",
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen
        };

        SaveConfirmationDg = new SaveConfirmationDialog(ref window);
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Note that the `Content` of the `Window` has not been set yet, I will document this after.

This is how the `DialogBox` looks like (upon pressing *OUI* or *NON*, the window should be closing but it isn't):

[image]

This is the xaml used to generate the `DialogBox` which is a `UserControl` nested into our `DialogBox Window`.

**SaveConfirmation.xaml**

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="350" Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="Voulez-vous enregistrer les modifications?" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Foreground="White" Content="OUI" Command="{Binding Close}" CommandParameter="close" Margin="10,0" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Foreground="White" Content="NON" Command="{Binding Close}" CommandParameter="close" Margin="10,0" />
        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>
```

As I am using the MVVM pattern,  I am setting the `DataContext` to **SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel.cs** in the `Code-Behind` (Note that the window created is passed as a reference).

```
public SaveConfirmationDialog(ref Window window)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel(ref window);
    }
```

Finally, here is how I create and assign the `Content` of the `DialogBox`:

**SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel.Cs**

```
 class SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public Window CurrentWindow;
    public MyICommand<string> Close { get; private set; }

    SaveConfirmationDialog SaveConfDg;

    public SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel(ref Window window)
    {
        SaveConfDg = new SaveConfirmationDialog();
        window.Content = SaveConfDg;
        window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        CurrentWindow = window;
        Close = new MyICommand<string>(ExitDialog);
    }

    private void ExitDialog(string exit)
    {
        CurrentWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

Note that `CurrentWindow` is assigned a reference of `window` to be able to use it outside of the `Constructor`. After pressing the *OUI* and *NON* buttons the `ExitDialog` method of the `Close command` should be used to close the `Window` but I see it's not even called because I have checked by placing a breakpoint.

I am thinking the problem might be with the DataContext. Does anyone have a clue what the problem might
be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused about what is `SaveConfirmationDialog` ? (or you mean `SaveConfirmation` ? ) Also how is `MyICommand` implemented ?

Comment: Why are you passing to a reference to the window to `SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was really simple, I just needed to comment out the first line of my `Constructor` and pass the `SaveConfirmationDialog` object from the `Code-Behind`

**SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel.cs**

```
public SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel(ref Window window, SaveConfirmationDialog SaveConfDg)
    {
        //SaveConfDg = new SaveConfirmationDialog();
        window.Content = SaveConfDg;
        window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        CurrentWindow = window;
        Close = new MyICommand<string>(ExitDialog);
    }
```

**SaveConfirmationDialog.xaml.cs**

```
public SaveConfirmationDialog(ref Window window)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Added this as second parameter
        DataContext = new SaveConfirmationDialogViewModel(ref window, this);
    }
```